# How to match data with an upload file in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have uploaded a file containing a list of cities called [Sandbox].[dbo].[Cities for Special Project]. I am trying to find out how revenue we are collecting from the cities in my list.

I can find out how much revenue we collect from each city thats already in my DB but I am unsure how on how to match that to the file that I uploaded.

```
Select individual.[vchCity] as City
       , sum(staging.[Price_PerLicense]) as Total
From Engine1.DB1.[dbo].[Individual] individual
Join
Engine2.DB2.[dbo].[Daily_License_Report_Detail] staging on individual.[iIndividualId] = staging.[OwnerId]
Group by individual.[vchCity]
```

How would I match what I have to the cities thats in my uploaded file.

Comment: Please provide more information (at least columns of the [Cities for Special Project] and some sample data).

Comment: Hi Farhad, theres only one column for my uploaded sheet. Its called City.

City
LA
St Louis
Tampa
Seattle
Chicago

Comment: So, If the `individual.[vchCity]` and the `City` columns are in the same type, you can simply join your totalPrice query with the `[Cities for Special Project]` table. Is it work for you?

Comment: Is this SQL Server or DB2?  They have different syntax's.

Comment: Thanks Farhad! It worked

Answer (score 0):

```
with CityTotal as(
Select individual.[vchCity] as City, sum(staging.[Price_PerLicense]) as Total
From Engine1.DB1.[dbo].[Individual] individual
Join Engine2.DB2.[dbo].[Daily_License_Report_Detail] staging on individual.[iIndividualId] = staging.[OwnerId]
Group by individual.[vchCity]
)

Select cs.city, ct.total
from [Sandbox].[dbo].[Cities for Special Project] cs 
left join cititytotal ct on ct.city = cs.city
```

This is one way